# How do I make MongoDB call generateIdIfAbsentFromDocument automatically?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a [`CollectibleCodec<Thing>`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/codecs/CollectibleCodec.html) which I use for interfacing with a MongoDB database:

```
public class ThingCodec implements CollectibleCodec<Thing> { /* ... */ }

// ...

MongoCollection<Thing> things = database
    .withCodecRegistry(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new ThingCodec()))
    .getCollection("things", Thing.class);
```

Reading and writing `Thing`s through this codec works just fine, but there's a hitch: The [`ThingCodec.generateIdIfAbsentFromDocument(Thing)`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/codecs/CollectibleCodec.html#generateIdIfAbsentFromDocument-T-) method is never called, so the things are saved in the database without IDs unless I set the ID before saving the thing. Is there any way to configure the MongoDB driver to call this method automatically when I insert or update items in the collection?

Comment: What is your implementation? You're not showing it here but it should look something like [this](https://gist.github.com/JaiHirsch/08397223c2a0de64dfc8#file-gradescodec-java-L78-L81). Please add the implementation if there is still a problem.

Comment: My mistake. I must have misunderstood my colleague. We tested the behaviour and saw that our debug logging in `generateIdIfabsentFromDocument` was not called, but when I try this myself I see that the method is in fact called. Thanks for taking your time to look at it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, one simple way is to do it in the `ThingCodec` itself:

```
public class ThingCodec implements CollectibleCodec<Thing> {

    @Override
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, Thing value, EncoderContext context) {
        generateIdIfAbsentFromDocument(value);
        // Do encoding
    }

    // ...
}
```